# UPDATE SQL no C# (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando formatar uma data padrão, pois há datas com formatos diferentes, conforme print abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

MM/dd/yyyy |
dd/MM/yyyy |
dd/MM/yyyy hh:MM:ss

Pretendo mudar essas datas para padrão como dd/MM/yyyy hh:MM:ss

Pensei em puxar as datas e depois clicar botão para atualizar os formatos das todas datas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que eu nao tenho ideia para fazer isso, travo na hora de fazer codigo.

```
public void AlteraData(Data newData)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = command.CommandText = "'UPDATE T410_CARGA SET T400_DTCHEGADA = '" + newData.Data;
            for (int linha = 0; linha <= 10; linha++)
            {
                newData.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM:ss");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Não entendi o porque do `for`, qual o motivo dele?

Comment: Eu não entendi porque ele está depois do update, que também não tem `where`. To achando inclusive que essa coluna no banco é um `varchar`.

Comment: Verdade, esqueci de colocar where. Exatamente que essa coluna é varchar.

Comment: @Barbetta o laço for irá formatar a cada linha que possui no banco. Mas acho que achei um jeito, irei postar meu codigo que eu fiz diferente lá em cima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz classe CultureInfo que converte a hora de PT e EN... Nesse caso eu converti de Ingles para Portugues.

```
public void AlteraData(DataTable newData)
        {
            CultureInfo cultura = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
            for (int linha = 0; linha < newData.Rows.Count; linha++)
            {
                DateTime data1 = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1900");
                string teste = newData.Rows[linha]["T400_DTCHEGADA"].ToString();
                var separador = teste.Split('/');
                //Console.Write(separador[0].ToString());
                if (Convert.ToInt32(separador[0]) > 12 || Convert.ToInt32(separador[1]) > 12)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        data1 = Convert.ToDateTime(teste, cultura);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        data1 = Convert.ToDateTime(teste);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    data1 = Convert.ToDateTime(teste, cultura); ;
                }
                var dataConvertida = data1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

                if (dataConvertida != "01/01/1900")
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(teste);

                    command.CommandText = "UPDATE T410_CARGA SET T400_DTCHEGADA = '" + dataConvertida + "' WHERE T400_DTCHEGADA = '" + teste + "'";
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    connection.Open(); 
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

O correto é: `newData.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");`

```
public void AlteraData(Data newData)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = command.CommandText = "'UPDATE T410_CARGA SET T400_DTCHEGADA = '" + newData.Data;
            for (int linha = 0; linha <= 10; linha++)
            {
                newData.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            }
        }
    }
```